# ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(imgStr)) returns null in JAR

Tags: java, jar, javax.imageio

I am having an issue loading images in my JAR file.
I am using :

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(imgStr));
```

Where imgStr is of the form "/xxxx.png".

I have two different .png images in the same location. 
One image, let's say /x.png loads fine.
The other image, /y.png give the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null
```

I can't find any reason for this.
Strangely, the everything works fine in the Eclipse environment.

Could it have something to do with the images being transparent?

Does anyone have an idea??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you state the actual name of x and y?

Comment: /H4000_1.png and /Cancel are the names. The first one throws and error, the second one not.

Comment: Well, I would make sure that character '_' isn't causing any trouble (probably not). Are you absolutely sure that you are putting in the correct file name into imgStr?

Comment: Yes I am sure. One thing I forgot to mention. In the eclipse environment everythingworks fine. It is only in the JAR that the problem happens!

Comment: I've now tried removing "_" in the name but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that some of the files were .PNG in capitals.
Apparently some programs save as ".png" and others as ".PNG".